# New to Js, how do i get the value of this request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Sorry if I've worded this badly, but I have some lines of js:

```js
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/test.txt');
client.onloadend = function() {
alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
var x =
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

How can I make var x = the value of the alert box?

Comment: um, put those lines where the alert is? `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = client.responseText;`

Comment: You have tagged this as `jquery`, yet you are not using jQuery for your AJAX GET request. Maybe you should use jQuery or remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/test.txt');
client.onload = e => {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.target.responseText);
};
client.send();
var x =
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```